# Showing that Column Vectors Corresponding to Nonzero Eigenvectors form a basis for R(*A*)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

A study buddy and I were going through this question and while we made some progress, we were ultimately unsure if what we were doing was correct or not.

The question is:

Let *A* be a diagonalizable matrix and let *X* be the diagonalizing matrix. Show that the column vectors of *X* correspond to the nonzero eigenvalues of *R*(*A*).

What we did was this:

Say that *A* is *n* x *n*. Therefore *X* must be *n* x *n* and a matrix *D* must be *n* x *n* since if A is diagonalizable and X is the diagonalizing matrix:

*A* = *X* *D* *X* $^{-1}$

Since *X* is invertible, its eigenvectors must be linearly independent. Therefore, because *X* is *n* x *n*, there are *n* linearly independent eigenvectors. These eigenvectors span $\mathbb{R}$$^n$.

Because of this, *R*(*A*) $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$$^n$, we've shown that the the column vectors of *X* correspond to the nonzero eigenvalues of *R*(*A*)... except we haven't. My buddy and I got stuck here and we weren't sure what to do since we haven't accounted for the eigenvalues that are equal to 0.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $\lambda_1,\dots\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ with associated eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1,\dots,\mathbf v_n$. Collect the equations $A\mathbf v_i=\lambda_i\mathbf v_i$ into a single equation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what to do with that information or how it's relevant.

Comment: The matrix product $AB$ can be viewed as $A$ acting on each column of $B$ individually, i.e., $AB=A(B_1,\dots,B_n)=(AB_1,\dots,AB_n)$. Going the other way, if you have a collection of products of a matrix $A$ with vectors, you can consolidate all of those products into one by collection all of the vectors into a single matrix.